# Power calculation to check if multiple predictive models are correlated

Tags: mathematical-statistics, correlation, variance, statistical-power, stacking

Say there is a classification setting so that $$ { \{(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2), ..., (x_n,y_n)\} } $$ is a set of $n$ observations, and then there is a set of $m$ estimators (models) that take an individual $ x $ and make predictions about $y$, so that, for the first pair of observations $ (x_1,y_1)$, there are $m$ predictions:

$$h^{(1)}(x_1)=\hat{y}_1^{(1)}, $$

$$h^{(2)}(x_1)=\hat{y}_1^{(2)}, $$
$$..., $$
$$h^{(m)}(x_1)=\hat{y}_1^{(m)} $$

In the end, the goal is to do majority voting or averaging, so uncorrelated models are preferred. My question is: how many samples $n$ do we need to determine whether the $m$ models are (un)correlated enough? Or, similarly, how many samples $n$ do we need to properly compute the variance between models?

So far, I have tried simulations of different levels of correlation between $h$'s, but I'm guessing there is a better way, perhaps a closed form?

Thanks!

Comment: The models should be correlated if they are any good. So the classification of one model should be more likely to resemble the classification of the other models.

Comment: Thanks @frank. Although bagging works best for uncorrelated estimators. In any case, the question can be rephrased as "what's the n needed to properly quantify correlation between models"?